# redirect html page and open new tab with different URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

in my page i need to use link so when the user click it a new tab will open and the old tab should be redirect to another URL i try this code but does not work

```
<a class="aaf" href="www.abc.com" target="_blank"></a>
```

i use class with the a tag and this is my script

```
$('.aaf').on("click",function(){

  window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
})
```

Comment: *"does not work"* is not enough information.  If you add a `console.log("test")` inside the click event, do you get that?  Does it open the "www.abc.com" link in a new tab? Are there any console errors?  Are you adding the link after your script? Does it "work" if you put your code inside document ready?  (wrap in `$(function() { $(".aaf")....`)

Comment: Be wary of crossing from secure content to non-secure content, as when I attempted to reproduce this it worked when using HTTPS on both URLs. Also note that the `href` attribute needs a protocol prefix on it, as it's an absolute address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve it, you need to add setTimeout to function like this.

```
function changeLocation (){
 setTimeout(function(){
  window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
 },200);
}
```